# Updating DOM tree in Java after appendChild

Tags: java, xml, dom, saxparser

My problem is, when I add new Child in the tree, I try to access this element by ID (document.getElementByID("id")) but returns null.

However, if I navigate since root element, to their children, this element appears.

What should I do?

I think it's a problem of indexing IDs

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a new child, please assign a ID with it.

If you don't assign a ID, you can't access it.

Ant try to add element in the div with a id.

It is a good practice.

Comment: isn't this a comment?

Comment: Yes,that was the problem. I only add an attribute that i consider the ID attribute in my DTD, but I did not specify which was the attribute ID.

Answer (score 0):

The solution, thanks to Abrar Jahin:

```
user.setAttribute("uId", text_uId); //add attribute to Element
user.setIdAttribute("uId", true); //specify the attribute is the ID
```

After that you can find this element int the DOM tree by ID

```
Element user = document.getElementById(text_uId);
```